# while update image text box image name is not coming

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

in .net MVC 5 with razor syntax I am trying to update the file but after click on update, the file name is not showing inside the textbox, for more clear picture please refer the image,
[image]

**cshtml code is**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.ReqLabelFor(model => model.file_path, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-5">
                                    @*@Html.TextBox("upload", null, new { type = "file", accept = "image/*", @class = "form-control" })*@
                                    @Html.TextBox("file", null, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.file_path, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**And c# code is**

```
File fileDownload = await db.File.Where(x => x.id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

> where file_path is of string type.

**But actually It should come like below image**
[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: code? stackoverflow needs to delete automatic questions that do not contain code

Comment: You cannot show like that. It is the browser which displays that name when user selects a file. You can still show the name you stored in the database, in a label next to the control.